# $ [0,1] \cup \mathbb{N} \sim [0,1] $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Prove that $ [0,1] \cup \mathbb{N} \sim [0,1] $ ( meaning, I need to prove equipotency ) by showing an **explicit bijection** ( Without Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem ).
I tried giving a function of the form
$ 
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{n} &\text{if}\, \exists n \in \mathbb{N^+}.x=n  \\
      x     &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
 $ , for all $ x \in [0,1] \cup \mathbb{N} $ ; However, this function is a mistake since it's not a bijection ( it's not one-to-one since for-example $ f(2)= f(1/2) $ ). I've been breaking my head over this problem, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an explicit bijection, you may interleave $1,2,3,...$ with $1/2, 1/3, ...$, by defining:

$f(1)=\frac{1}{2}, f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{3}, f(2)=\frac{1}{4}, f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{5}, f(3)=\frac{1}{6}, f\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{7}$ and so on, in general:

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2n}, & \text{if } x\in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}\\
\frac{1}{2n-1}, & \text{if } x=\frac{1}{n}. n\in \{2, 3, ...\}\\
x, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $X = \{ \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \Bbb{N}^+\}$, then $[0, 1]$ is the disjoint union $([0, 1] \setminus X) \cup X$ and $X \sim \Bbb{N}$. Now use an explicit bijection of $\Bbb{N}$ and the disjoint union $\Bbb{N} \sqcup \Bbb{N}$ to get a bijection of $[0, 1] \cup \Bbb{N}$ with $\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: Why  $ \Bbb{N} \sqcup \Bbb{N} $ a disjoint union? $ \mathbb{N} \cup \mathbb{N} = \mathbb{N} $

Comment: He uses $\mathbb{N}$, with the meaning of "countable cardinality", basically he says that the union of two countable sets is countable.

Comment: $\Bbb{N} \sqcup\Bbb{N}$ is the disjoint union of two copies of $\Bbb{N}$. It can be concretely represented as $(\{0\} \times \Bbb{N}) \cup (\{1\} \times \Bbb{N}) \subseteq \Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{N}$ and can be identified with $\Bbb{N}$ by using the even numbers for the first copy and the odd numbers for the second.